# Раздельно связывание как способ борьбы с коллизиями в хеш-таблице

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование, структуры-данных

Необходимо реализовать борьбу с коллизиями методом раздельного связывания. Однако на просторах интернета мне не удалось найти какую либо информацию касательно этого метода. Возможно у него есть другое, более распространённое название?

Answer (score 2):

Я вот тоже посмотрел на это и понял, что я такого не знаю. Но благодаря "обратному переводу через гугл" я восстановил название. Это называется в английском Separate Chaining - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashing-set-2-separate-chaining/ (там есть картинки!) или классика - [wiki -> Hash_table -> Separate_chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) или [ru wiki - Метод цепочек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Суть очень проста и популярна - внутри хеш-таблица хранится как массив фиксированного размера, элементы которого - связанные списки. По хешу ключа определяем элемент массива (bucket - корзину) (если нужно - делим по модулю на размер массива, который обычно простое число) и потом смотрим в списке, нет ли такого элемента и действуем соответствующее (добавляем/удаляем/модифицируем).

Если с хешем не угадали, будет перекос, в этом случае иногда меняют либо хеш, либо размер массива (скорее всего увеличивают).